# How to get to Twine Peaks after the new Canny Valley storyline?

Tags: fortnite-save-the-world

So I was at Stormshield defense 6 before the new system came out. After the new system I was set back in my questprogress. Now after finally having reached page 7/7 in the new system at Defense 3, it seems like I can't progress any further.

Am I seeing this wrong? Or how am I supposed to get to Twine Peaks now. I am now already on PL 81 and can't do any missions higher than 70 not to mention the 250ish skillpoints I have already gathered over the time.

Answer (score 2):

They moved ssd to side quests but if you do canny ssd 1-6 a new side quest pops and it's blasting off, do that and you'll get twine peaks

Comment: Is this actually true now for everyone? Or just for those who were already that far before the patch? Or what are the exact prequesites to unlock these side quests? I am in twine peaks now, so +1 and thanks for the solution, but would like to have a bit more complete answer before I'd acept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

After completing Canny SSD 6, you'll get a quest to launch the rocket, and then you will gain access to Twine. Make sure you have pl 70+, or else you'll have trouble completing any missions in Twine.

Answer (score 1):

If you do 6 ssd in canney you will have a side quest that should be called time to blast off, thats how i'm in canney but still on quest page 8 in plankerton. (just make sure you are pl 70+